# Folder structure of Azure function Nodejs

Tags: azure-functions

The folder structure of azure function nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required folder structure for a JavaScript project looks like the following. This default can be changed with [scriptFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#using-scriptfile).

```
FunctionsProject
 | - MyFirstFunction
 | | - index.js
 | | - function.json
 | - MySecondFunction
 | | - index.js
 | | - function.json
 | - SharedCode
 | | - myFirstHelperFunction.js
 | | - mySecondHelperFunction.js
 | - node_modules
 | - host.json
 | - package.json
 | - extensions.csproj
```

Further more information, you could refer to this official doc:[Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node).

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Where we will set .env variable Thanks

Comment: @Gopal Meena, what do you mean .env variable? What's that for?

Comment: set database configuration purpose dev or prod, like expressjs framework

Comment: @Gopal Meena,You don't know where to set the environment. From the doc I linked, there is a [Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#environment-variables) description, yo ucould set it in app settings and accesss it with `process.env(env_name)`.

Comment: Thanks, @George Chen it's very helpful for me